# Regular Expression for email validation fails

Tags: regex, email-validation

Below regular expression for email validation,

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Here I couldn't understand the `[\w\.-]` purpose. Can any one please let me know?

Use this pattern,

If I give `a@test.com` in a email field, validation becomes fail. In email string before `@` if just one character or numeric comes the validation become fail. Is this right?

Regards,
karthik

Comment: This is for Javascript? BTW, the regex looks wrong for its purpose. Where did you get it from? This would be a **[proper regular expression](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)** for email address validation.

Comment: why people want to use regex for e-mail validation? there are enough libraries for this task

Comment: @loldop: Can you please tell me libraries other than regex for email validation?

Comment: @Karthik yeah, i can: https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Valid. This is perl solution.

Comment: hey check out my answer. see if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

`[\w.-]` means a single character that is either:

- A word character (alphanumeric or `_`)
- `.`
- `-`

`a@test.com` fails because this regular expression requires at least 2 characters before the `@`.

Comment: The trivial fix would be to change `[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]` into `([\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?` i.e. make the part after the first character optional (and remove the superfluous backslash in the character class).

Comment: @tripleee I can't tell from the original question whether rejecting a@test.com is desirable or not :P.

Comment: Ah, maybe the question is really "should I fix this"? Yes, you should.

Answer (score -1):

Use this regular expression for validating email id. Works fine for me

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Mark as answer if that worked for you :)